# How to deploy and use latest version of maven project

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have implemented a maven-java project ( say name : projA) and deployed it as jar.

Now, I have multiple Gradle-java projects ( say projB and projC) and both are using projA as a dependency. And both projB and projC need to use same version of projA as dependency.

**Problem is** :
**projA is changing it's version frequently** (being under development). So, now it's **developer's overhead** to update the version **everywhere** ( like projB and projC and more) it's been used in as a dependency.

**Question:**
Was wondering if there is a way to declare a version as **latest** at the **projA ( in pom.xml)** and can be pulled in (**in gradle.build in projB and projC**) as :

```
 implement '<group-id>:projB:latest'
```

So that developers do not have to track "how many places", "what version" etc to be synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a snapshot version in the dependencies, that's the definition of an "under development" module that keeps changing.The "-SNAPSHOT" suffix has to be added in the end of the original version and this is effectively working the same way as a hypothetical "latest" version.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "groupId", name: "artifactId", version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```